# Hover in the meaning "to remain suspended under"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

In most dictionaries the word **hover** means *"to remain suspended over a place or object"* and *"to hang fluttering in the air or on the wing"*. Sometimes *"to float in the air without moving in any direction"*.

I would like to know if I can use it to speak about an object or person who is floating in the air under [something], a ceiling for instance. Is there a better word for that?

- The drone was hovering right under (below) the ceiling. *(by request of SteveES)*

Comment: I'd probably say "...just below the ceiling".  If we say "the drone was hovering below the bridge" it could be anywhere from just above water level up to the bridge span, but "*just* below the bridge" would mean "not far from the bottom of the bridge span".

Comment: *Below* the ceiling sounds better to me too.  I admit I'm not sure why, since really "below the ceiling" and "under the ceiling" mean essentially the same thing, but everything in the room is "under the ceiling".

Comment: Even if you say "The drone was hovering under (below) the ceiling.", we know logically that it was hovering over the floor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could say, "The drone hovered below/under the roof line." The definition says nothing about over or under -- it means 'suspended'.

> Hover -- Google Dictionary
>
> verb
>
> 1. remain in one place in the air. "army helicopters hovered overhead"
>
> synonyms:  be suspended, be poised, hang, levitate, float; fly
>   "helicopters hovered overhead"
>
> noun
>
> 1. an act of remaining in the air in one place.

Comment: You beat me to it!